# Why does Back To My Mac work for my Time Capsule, but not my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, time-capsule, back-to-my-mac

I'm having problems using Back To My Mac from work to my home network. Initially, I thought it was something to do with the way the work network had been set up, but recently I realised that I have no problems connecting to my Time Capsule… It's just that I can't connect to my MacBook Pro. It is showing up in the devices on the left panel, but when I try to connect to it, I get this message:
[image]

So why is it I can connect to the Time Capsule HD okay, but not the Mac?

---

UPDATE 1: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I do get a warning message on my work connection:
[image]
However, this states that the connection might be slow, not non-existant. I have no control over how the work network is setup, but considering I can access the Time Capsule at home, I don't imagine this is the problem.

My home machine is running OS X 10.8.2 and my work machine is running 10.7.4.

There are certain troubleshooting tips that deal with Keychain Access if coming from MobileMe to iCloud. I will look into this next.

Comment: It is nearly impossible for anyone to help you based on the limited information you have provided. Visit this page and follow the troubleshooting details. If they don't help, scroll to the bottom of the page and edit your post above with all the necessary details about your network configuration and setup: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4907

Comment: I would love to see an answer for this. I would either have this error or a message requesting that I should disable double NAT for better performance. My Time Capsule is in Bridge mode, and all firewalls are off from the router modem down to individual devices.

Comment: @cksum - thanks, I will follow the troubleshooting tips on the page and see if I can come up with any solutions. In the meantime, I have some extra information so I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks to the troubleshooting, I have discovered that my office network has "Double NAT" (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1208) - two levels of NAT, which apparently can mean that some machines will show up but not connect (exactly what I am getting). I guess I will have to contact my network administrator and ask them if there's anything they can do about that (I guess not, which is a big shame). If they can't, am I all out of options?